# Copy the values in a range from a workbook and append to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

The code I'm using at present works however it goes via the clipboard.
What changes would be needed to bypass the clipboard.

```
wb.Worksheets("FullAnalysis").Range("A11:AO16").Copy
wbDATA.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If you have an answer you feel solved your problem, you can select it by clicking the check mark next to it.  That will help future readers know you have a solution, if they are looking for similar issues, or also save people from reading through the comments to see that you don't need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the values directly:

```
wbDATA.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(16, 41).Value2 = wb.Worksheets("FullAnalysis").Range("A11:AO16").Value2
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Rory. Not clear about the Resize(16,41) element and its purpose. why 16? why 41?

Comment: Getting there Rory. The 41 gives an array of 41 columns as per the source range. (My pennies take a long time to drop) Presumably the 16 could be changed to the number of rows in the source data, in my case 6.

Comment: Excellent Rory, thanks again. Ran the code you advised, changed the Resize to (6,41), worked perfectly..

Comment: Yes - sorry that was a typo and the 16 was meant to be 6! Glad you figured it out.